# Finding Java classes and/or methods unsupported by GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I want to use a third-party library, for which I have the source code, in my GWT project.

Right now, it's failing with the well-known "No source code is available for type...; did you forget to inherit a required module" message. I understand that error to be caused by the dependence of the third-party library on a class/method that is not emulated by GWT.

I'm in a pickle because the GWT compiler does not inform me which class/method in the third-party library is causing it to barf. I kind of expected that a lint-like tool for finding unsupported Java constructs would be included in Google's GWT downloads, but I can't find it.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if the library doesn't specify to be GWT-compliant, I wouldn't use it. GWT has some black holes that make sense, because the browser is totally different compared to the JVM.

I don't know of any tool to check which class is not GWT-compliant, but I think that you could do it using [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html). The idea is to run `JDepend` specifying the classes that can be used: the [emulated JRE classes](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html) plus other GWT libraries that you use.

Answer (score 0):

if the code does not depend on incompatible classes, you could just write your own .gwt.xml file for the library and inherit from that too in your own .gwt.xml file.